# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 When JsonString parsing in Swift5

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm getting a push message. It seems to be jsonString.

But this is not changed into jsonArray.  What's the problem?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
        guard
            let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let body = alert["body"] as? String
            else {
                Log.Error("it's not good data")
                return
        }
        let jsonStringData : Data = body.data(using: .utf8)!
        Log.Info(jsonStringData)
        do {
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonStringData, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]

                Log.Info(jsonArray) // use the json here

        } catch let error as NSError {
            Log.Error(error)
        }
```

**Value of body (String)**

```
{ 
    notification : {

                            "title" : "test title.",  

                            "body" : "test context."            

                      },

     data : {

                    "image" : "http://11.111.111.111:100000000/_img/sample_01.jpg",  

                    "page_url" : "http://11.111.111.111:100000000/test?address=",   

                    "type" : "test"       

             }
}
```

The log of body is like this in JSON form. But this is not translated. I don't know what I'm missing.

**Error is : **

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in
>   object around character 7." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key
>   for value in object around character 7.}

Comment: Not related but, no need for `.allowFragments`. There should be doubles quotes around "notification" and "data". You can copy/past the output in a JSON validator, you'll see...

Comment: Code 3840 means it’s not valid JSON and it even shows you the reason and the position where it fails.

Comment: @Larme How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Sh_Khan How to solve it??

Comment: Hi @vadian  How to solve it??

Comment: You don't need to do anything, ask your backend guy to send a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks you for all @Larme , Sh_Khan , vadian,  Kamran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for @vadian and  @Larme and @Sh_Khan and @Kamran

As you said, `JSON` was not valid. This should have been received by `JSON`. And as @Larme said, I didn't need options, I didn't need to set `as`. It rather showed me a warning.

It's worked

```swift
guard
    let aps = data[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
    let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
    let body = alert["body"] as? String
else {
    Log.Error("it's not good data")
    return
}
let jsonStringData : Data = body.data(using: .utf8)!
Log.Info(jsonStringData)
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonStringData, options: [])
    
    Log.Info(json) // use the json here
    guard let jsonArray = json as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    Log.Debug(jsonArray)
    Log.Debug(jsonArray["data"])
    
} catch let error as NSError {
    Log.Error(error)
}
```